# Android Room selecting a row with query

Tags: java, database, android-room

I am new to using the Room functionality and I have setup my Dao with the following

public interface ValleyDao {

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM event_filter ORDER BY filter_name ASC")
LiveData<List<EventFilter>> getAllEventsFilters();

@Query("SELECT * FROM event_filter LIMIT 1")
EventFilter[] getAnyEventFilter();

@Query("SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY event_millis ASC")
LiveData<List<Events>> getAllEvents();

@Query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_filter = :event_filter")
LiveData<List<Events>> getFilteredEvents(List<Events> event_filter);

@Query("SELECT * FROM events LIMIT 1")
Events[] getAnyEvent();

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
void insertNewEvents(Events events);

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
void insertNewEventFilters(EventFilter eventFilter);

@Delete
void deleteEvent(Events events);

@Query("DELETE FROM events")
void deleteAllEvents();

@Update
void update(Events... events);
```

}

The query that is giving me issues is the query:

@Query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_filter = :event_filter")
LiveData> getFilteredEvents(List event_filter);

I have a numerical filter assigned in a column so I can sort the data out. I am trying to get that integer so I can display the proper items in the recyclerview. I am not sure what to put in the VeiwModeler to limit it. So far my ViewModeler looks like the following:

```
public class ValleyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private DataRepository mRepository;

private LiveData<List<Events>> mAllEvents;

private LiveData<List<EventFilter>> mAllEventsFilter;

public ValleyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    mRepository = new DataRepository(application);
    mAllEvents = mRepository.getmAllEvents();
    mAllEventsFilter = mRepository.getmAllEventFilters();
}

LiveData<List<Events>> getAllEvents() {
    return mAllEvents;
}

LiveData<List<EventFilter>> getmAllEventsFilter() {return mAllEventsFilter;}



public void insert(Events events) {
    mRepository.insert(events);
}

public void deleteAll() {
    mRepository.deleteAll();
}

public void deleteWord(Events events) {
    mRepository.deleteWord(events);
}

public void update(Events events) {
    mRepository.update(events);
}
```

}

How can I use WHERE criteria in ROOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing for the solution:

In the Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_filter = :event_id")
LiveData<List<Events>> findSpecificEvent(long event_id);
```

LiveData makes it to where I am not running on the main UI thread.

No changes were needed int AppDatabase(the abstract class in the Room structure).

In the Repository: (It works but I am not sure if this is the best way)

```
public LiveData<List<Events>> getmCertainEvents(long eventsId) {
            return mDao.findSpecificEvent(eventsId);
    }
```

In the ViewModeler:

```
LiveData<List<Events>> getmCertainEvents(long eventId) {
      return mRepository.getmCertainEvents(eventId);
}
```

and finally in my List Activity:

```
final EventRecyclerAdapter adapter = new EventRecyclerAdapter(this);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

            // Set up the WordViewModel.
            mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ValleyViewModel.class);
   mViewModel.getmCertainEvents(FILTERLEVEL).observe(this, new Observer<List<Events>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Events> events) {
                        // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
                        adapter.setEvents(events);

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

"I am not sure what to put in the VeiwModeler to limit it", if understood properly, you want limit the query.

Based on my understanding, this is done in the `Dao` class, for example, within `ValleyDao` where you will run the SQLite query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = :event_id")
Event findSpecificEvent(long event_id);
```

In the above code example, I'm trying to find a specific event whose `id` is `1`. Then in `Repository`:

```
public Event findSpecificEvent(long event_id) {
    return mValleyDao.findSpecificEvent(event_id);
}
```

In `ViewModel` class:

```
public Event findSpecificEvent(long event_id) {
    return mRepository.findSpecificEvent(event_id);
}
```

In calling class where I want to pass the `Event` to `recyclerView`'s `adapter`:

```
Event event = mViewModel.findSpecificEvent(1);
// An example to pass it to recyclerVeiw
recyclerViewAdapter.setEvent(event);
```

Remember that while using the above example, you need to do this on a background thread.